# Error show data when event click livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have an error when showing the data I do not see the problem because the data does not want to show it I hope you can help me.

this my event click on table its work display my modal

```xml
<td>
  <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="edit({{$pais->id}})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update_pais">
    <i class="fa fa-search text-warning"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

This is my component function edit

```php
public $testNew;

public function edit(Pais $pais)
{
    $this->testNew = '324234234234';
}
```

this my input

```xml
<input wire:model="testNew" type="text">
```

when click data doesn't show and input is empty on network show data is correct

Comment: is the model binding work? did you check the `$pais` variable passed in to edit function. there could be an error on that so `testNew`  isn't updated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `value` attribute to your input?

```
<input wire:model="testNew" type="text" value="{{ $testNew }}">
```